# PHP SQL Syntax Error set variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying to deal with the problem in php which i have no experince.
I am trying to execute a very simple mysql command. The command works well on mysql workbench but due to some reason it gives an error in php if i declare a variable called ID.

I tested the sql query and it works..

Any help will be apreciated

Here is the php code:

```
$Date=date("Y/m/d");
$KonuBaslik=$_POST["baslik"];
$KonuCoverURL=$_POST["kapak"];
$icerik=htmlentities($_POST["konu_icerik"]);
$KonuIcerik=htmlentities($icerik);

$query="use blogdb;"."Start Transaction;".
"begin;"."set @ID=(select ifNull(MAX(konuID),0)+1 from konu);".
"INSERT INTO konu VALUES (?,?,?,'".$Date."',@ID);".
"commit;";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
echo $mysqli->error;
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $KonuBaslik,$KonuIcerik,$KonuCoverURL);   

$stmt->execute();
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add column names for table `konu`

Try this..

```
$Date=date("Y/m/d");
$KonuBaslik=$_POST["baslik"];
$KonuCoverURL=$_POST["kapak"];
$icerik=htmlentities($_POST["konu_icerik"]);
$KonuIcerik=htmlentities($icerik);
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username, $password, $dbname);
$konuID = $mysqli->query("select MAX(konuID) from konu")->fetch_array()[0] + 1;

$query = "INSERT INTO konu(`column names`,``,``,``,``)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
echo $mysqli->error;
$stmt->bind_param('sssss',$KonuBaslik,$KonuIcerik,$KonuCoverURL,$Date,$konuID);   

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: ID is a mysql variable. It stores the biggest ID of the table konu so that i can implement kind a auto increment there. The reason i do this instead of using auto increment is to be able to add a row with specific id in the future. From this aspect, I have to use Transactions.. Considering ID as a php var is not very proper in this position for me..

Comment: I am sorry, still the same output : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Start Transaction;begin;set @ID=(select ifNull(MAX(konuID),0)+1 from konu);INSER' at line 1

Comment: Many thanks for your effort :)   I am gonna try this code as soon as i can and push the result. By the way , apologise because of my bad language skills